# ASP MVC OWIN loses authentification on debug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am using OWIN 3.0.1 for .Net 4.6.1.

Project folder added to IIS as application **http://localhost/prj**

I have strange effect.

- login in site (all ok, cookie is set)
- run debug from Visual studio
- refresh page (controller used [System.Web.Mvc.Authorize], cookie is set)
- **user are not logged** in and will redirected to /Account/Login
- stop debug
- refresh page again
- **user are logged in**

I have same scenario in other projects but not same problem.

Comment: Can you create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @IvanMilosavljevic I can not create. This is problem only with one project. I see this problem a first time.